# ADW lock code forgotten

Tags: adw.launcher

Using ADWLauncher, you can lock the desktop. Extremely useful, till the password is forgotten.

I have a Nexus 4. Any solution to crack the password?

Comment: I don't know if the settings export would export the lock as well. So you could try export, then delete the data from ADW, then import settings again. In the worst case you are were you started -- with some luck the lock was not exported along. -- With some shit the password is exported plain text and you can read it (unlikely, but not impossible).

Comment: (alternative method)If you know `adb`, you can push another homescreen app. ex: *Zeam Laucher*. Then press `home` button and select the alternative homescreen app. This method worked on a galaxy mini.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Sqlite browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/):

If you can get to the phone's internal storage from your PC, try finding the. Sql files.with the code stored. Well, provided its a numeric code; if its a swipe patter, you're s.o.l. and have to do a reset of the phone.